# Run a Jmeter Test from a webpage

Tags: javascript, java, web, jmeter

At the moment this is untested, and not attempted, I am asking moreso in theory.

What I am hoping to do, is use the "Jmeter Dashboard Report" page as an internal testing reporting website. On this site, I would like to have a link/button somewhere on the page to run 1 of X Jmeter tests. The tests would not be run through GUI (Preferably), and after the test has ran the page will refresh with the new results.

I have searched on google for anything similar to this, with no luck.

I am basically wondering if something like this would be possible to do? Or if I should rethink what I am hoping to do.

Answer (score 0):

[Check this thread](http://%20How%20To%20Use%20Apache%20JMeter%20To%20Perform%20Load%20Testing%20on%20a%20Web%20Server)

1. The first step you want to do with every `JMeter Test Plan` is to add a `Thread Group element`. The `Thread Group` tells `JMeter` the number of users you want to simulate, how often the users should send requests, and how many requests they should send.
2. Go ahead and add the `ThreadGroup` element by first selecting the `Test Plan`, clicking your right mouse button to get the ``` Add menu``, and then select Add ``` → `ThreadGroup`.
3. You should now see the `Thread Group` element under `Test Plan`. If you do not see the element, then "expand" the `Test Plan tree` by clicking on the Test Plan element.
4. Next, you need to modify the default properties. Select the T`hread Group element` in the tree, if you have not already selected it. You should now see the `Thread Group Control Panel` in the right section of the `JMeter window`
5. Start by providing a more descriptive name for our Thread Group. In the name field, enter JMeter Users.
6. Next, increase the number of users (called threads) to 5.
7. In the next field, the Ramp-Up Period, leave the default value of 1 seconds. This property tells `JMeter` how long to delay between starting each user. For example, if you enter a Ramp-Up Period of 5 seconds, JMeter will finish starting all of your users by the end of the 5 seconds. So, if we have 5 users and a 5 second Ramp-Up Period, then the delay between starting users would be 1 second (5 users / 5 seconds = 1 user per second). If you set the value to 0, then JMeter will immediately start all of your users.
8. Finally enter a value of 2 in the Loop Count field. This property tells JMeter how many times to repeat your test. If you enter a loop count value of 1, then JMeter will run your test only once. To have JMeter repeatedly run your Test Plan, select the Forever checkbox.

Comment: I apologize, but I understand how Jmeter works.. I was more or less looking for any recommendations on how to: 
Be on a webpage: MyJmeterSite.com 
Click a Link: Run Jmeter Test #2 
Loading Screen: Wait till test completed 
Reload Webpage: Test results are reloaded and visible

Answer (score 0):

You can write an HTML that call on click/submit batch process of non GUI JMeter:

Start with`jmeter -n -t` and add your test name as test.jmx

After it add to command [generate dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) file, I assume , to get results as: `-e -o results.html`

In the HTML you can add iframe that will be refresh with JMeter dashboard results file.

Of course it can be done with JSP or full MVC project, but I gave the basic guidelines.